# Scrapy 403 for unknown reason, scrapy hangs in shell

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy 2.1.0
trying to scrape this url:
https://www.livingsocial.com/deals/kenny-s-ribs-and-dusty-s-buffet-1

But I get an error:

```
 DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.livingsocial.com/deals/kenny-s-ribs-and-dusty-s-buffet-1> (referer: https://www.livingsocial.com/local/chicago/restaurants) ['partial']
```

also running command:

```
scrapy shell https://www.livingsocial.com/deals/kenny-s-ribs-and-dusty-s-buffet-1
```

does not work and hangs on:

```
 INFO: Spider opened
```

how can I debug it ? to see what is causing the reason ? thanks!

Comment: It is not Scrapy, it also happens with cURL: `curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" https://www.livingsocial.com/deals/kenny-s-ribs-and-dusty-s-buffet-1`. It looks like antibot measures by the website.

Answer (score 0):

ah I needed just to set USER_AGENT to resolve the issue